# Python script to do a GET request on 2 urls in a cron job

Tags: python, cron

I need a python script to perform a GET request on 2 urls.

I will use these scripts in a cron job on my ubuntu server.

The catch is, the 2 calls have to happen sequentially because the first GET request to Url#1 might take up to 1 minute or so to complete.

For the cron job, I want it to run every 30 minutes.

Comment: So whats the problem? Just use urllib2.

Comment: Are you asking how to set up a crontab as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm missing something in your question.  But it should be fairly simple with urllib2:

```
import urllib2

request = urllib2.Request('http://example.com/path')
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
content = response.read()

# now make the second request, just as above
```

See the page, [urllib2 The Missing Manual](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml) for more help with the urllib2 module.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read the documentation of urllib:

http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib.urlretrieve("http://www.google.com")
('/tmp/tmpfYqXGp', <httplib.HTTPMessage instance at 0x109c878>)
>>> urllib.urlcleanup()
>>>
```